# amd and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, amd

I am working on a combination of `coffeescript` and `require.js` for AMD.

The problem would be that I must return a value for each module loaded by `require.js`, and I do that. But.. coffeescript helps me out and appends:`(function() {` and `}).call(this);`. which blows my code.

`main.js`

```
require.config( {
    paths: {
        'backbone':         'libs/AMDbackbone-0.5.3',
        'underscore':       'libs/underscore-1.2.2',
        'text':             'libs/require/text',
        'jquery':           'libs/jquery-1.7.1',
    },
    baseUrl: '/app'
} );

require(
        ['require', 'backbone', 'jquery', 'underscore' ],
        function( require, Backbone, $, _ ) {
            // framework loaded
            require(
                    ['require', 'app'],
                    function( require, app) {
                        return {};
                    } );
        } );
```

`app.js`

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/gameview',
], function( $, _, Backbone, GameView, ) {
    "use strict";

    window.app = {};

    $(function(){

        var app = window.app = _.extend({

            views: {
                GameView: new GameView
            },
            //code..
        }, window.app);

    //code...
    return window.app;
} );
```

**And the coffeescript:**

`/views/gameview.coffee`

```
define ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], ($, _, Backbone, RankView) ->
  "use strict"
  GameView = Backbone.View.extend()
  GameView
```

Which translates to:

`/views/gameview.js`

```
(function() {

  define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], function($, _, Backbone) {
    "use strict";

    var GameView;
    GameView = Backbone.View.extend({...});
    return GameView;
  });

}).call(this);
```

But I would like to translate to:

```
  define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], function($, _, Backbone) {
    "use strict";

    var GameView;
    GameView = Backbone.View.extend({...});
    return GameView;
  });
```

Would be nice to use this in console: `var GameView = new app.views.GameView;` in console.

How do I force coffeescript compiler not to do that? Is there a flag or something for that?

AGAIN: I JUST WANT TO CUT OFF `(function() {` and `}).call(this);` - is not that important the amd code behind it, be it global or not..

Thank you

Comment: Why would it not work? Your code does not rely on being executed in the global scope, does it?

Comment: I think this will answer your question http://blog.toastymofo.net/2012/04/coffeescript-requirejs-and-you-part-one.html

Comment: @Bergi Yes it does. Not a good solution for now, but I also need to debug it later via console. - would be nice

Comment: Try to use require.js shim then

Comment: @vittore - No, it doesn't. I just need to cut off `(function() {` and `}).call(this);` without any proxies, or other server-side techniques.

Comment: @Gamster: And where does it? Please show us that part of the code. Or do you expect something of the above to be a global variable?

Comment: @Bergi edited. Hope I give more information about the issue now. ty

Comment: @Gamster: OK. Still, cutting of the first and last line won't help. To solve the issue, just add `app.views = {GameView: GameView};` to the `gameview.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--bare` flag when compiling your coffee files:

> `-b`, `--bare`     Compile the JavaScript without the top-level function safety wrapper.